# Change datasource of a second LookUp based on a first LookUp's value for in-place form

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use a `XtraGrid` which it's editing mode is `EditFormInplace`.
I have populated `datasources` of all the `LookUps` when page is loaded. Now in runtime when `LookUp1` selects an item, I need to change the `datasource` of `LookUp2`.

How can I achieve this?
"Change `datasource` of `LookUp2`  based on a `LookUp1's` value for **in-place** form."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the built-in functionality for [cascading lookups](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument116018):

```
lookUpEdit2.CascadingOwner = lookUpEdit1;
```

> I use a XtraGrid which it's editing mode is EditFormInplace.

Every time the Edit Form is displayed, the [GridView.EditFormPrepared](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_EditFormPreparedtopic) event fires. 
Thus, you can use this event to access controls within the Edit Form:

```
void gridView1_EditFormPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.EditFormPreparedEventArgs e) {
    var lookupEdit1  = e.BindableControls[colLookup1] as LookupEdit;
    var lookupEdit2  = e.BindableControls[colLookup2] as LookupEdit;
    // ... customize editors
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, My problem is, I cant access 'lookupEdit2' object because its in 'in-place edit form'. There is no 'lookupEdit2' that I can use as u mentioned.

Comment: I did as u mentioned in update. Now problem is 'lookupEdit1' doesn't contain definition for 'CascadingOwner'.

Comment: I guess 'CascadingOwner' is not for in-place Edit form. I don't know how to filter them 'EditFormInplace' mode. I appreciate any help.